# accidentally deleted mysql folder

Tags: mysql

I am in a problem. I have accidentally deleted etc/mysql by writing *sudo rm -r /etc/mysql*
.How can i restore it or if not then what to do next .when I am typing mysql command its saying :

> Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (13)
>   what to do next ?

Comment: do you have a backup? /etc/mysql has "only" configuration files, right, not your database?

Comment: that is about as non accidentally an issue I've ever seen. "I accidentally died when I pointed a gun at my head and pulled the trigger - how do I fix it?"... This is a natural selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your most recent backups and restore all the files. And. if you don't have a recent backup, *why the blazes not?*

Assuming you can get the information back using what will undoubtedly be some good answers here, *institute a backup policy!*. Disk space is ridiculously cheap.

Marked CW since it doesn't answer your specific problem but it *is* useful, mark my words. Anyone who reads this answer and doesn't back up their stuff in a timely manner, take heed, you *will* get burnt (and, if it's your digital photo collection of wife and kids from the last ten years, your wife will have every right to castrate you while you sleep).

If this happens to you again, you deserve all the angst you'll get and I will openly mock and deride you :-)

Comment: there are 2 types of admins: those who have lost data, and those who have not ... yet. But it is not funny when it happens to you.

Comment: Asshat, this has nothing to do with OP's question. Once /etc/mysql get deleted, all mysql-* packages install/remove will fail.

Comment: @sdaffa23fdsf, the fact that the OP accepted the answer appears to indicate otherwise. And you may want to check your facts - you appear to be saying that the deletion of a directory means you can never recover from that. I have to challenge that since, if you put *everything* back the way it was, it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

What about just reinstalling mysql then?

Comment: I have tried but not working.....

Comment: @yosanu: well - if you have reinstalled `/etc` - you have to get the fresh and ready to work mysql.

Comment: @zerkms how to do that.

Comment: @yosanu: I'm sorry, but I think you need to learn linux basics?

Comment: @zerkms KO fine.....bebye